# Compile a libjingle dll

Tags: c++, libjingle

Hello I am trying to build a dll from Libjingle API, I want to be able to use Audio and Video in an XMPP Client on Windows.

I am able to build the libjingle source code using:

```
hammer.bat --jobs=6 --verbose --mode=all all_programs
```

I wanted to do this first to make sure it was working. I am also able to generate the Visual Studio Projects. But I am unsure what to do from there, I know how to set my project files to build as a dll but it seems there is no source code loaded in to each of the projects, (they are just empty projects).

I built the Visual Studio projects by following the instructions in main.scons file

```
s = vs_env.ComponentVSSolution(
     'libjingle',  # Please uncomment this line if you build VS proj files.
    ['all_libraries', 'all_programs', 'all_test_programs'], 
    projects = [p],
  )
```

then executing this command.

```
hammer --mode=all --vsproj
```

As I understand it I need to add the source files to each of the projects. But I am unsure how to do this or what should go where.

I appreciate any help you have to offer

*cheers

Edit I found this link with a Visual Studio Project premade http://code.google.com/p/libjingle/issues/detail?id=242

For anyone looking to do this :-)

Comment: If that's an answer to your own problem you should post it as an answer below - thanks! Then you can accept it as the solution, we can vote it up, etc.

Comment: Hey I don't think I have the permissions to answer my own questions. It didn't solve the problem of compiling a DLL, but cheers :-)